# Cannot Create Flutter Project in Android Studio due to missing pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Whenever I create the Create new Flutter Project in android studio,
It's always throwing out this error: Please help.

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/<usrname>/AndroidStudioProjects/inventory_system". pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/<usrname>/AndroidStudioProjects/inventory_system".)
```

Comment: Use this command in a terminal: `flutter create <project-name>`

Comment: Same error @stacktrace2234
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/<usrname>/AndroidStudioProjects/sample_proj".

Running "flutter pub get" in sample_proj...                             
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in
"/Users/<usrname>/AndroidStudioProjects/sample_proj".)

Comment: first of all make sure your flutter is properly installed on your system. I too had faced the same issue. Try checking your installation and make sure everything is installed properly. Use this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Comment: Just uninstall android as well as flutter. Try installing them again. First download and install Flutter. Then download and install Android Studio. Follow the proper installation process. I guess your issue is because of the unproper installation

Comment: reinstalling flutter and android studio fixed everything. Thank you so much! If you like, please use this as an "Answer" to this question then I'll mark it as the correct and helpful one :) @Itidi

Comment: @CodeGeek yes sure. I am glad this helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure your flutter is properly installed on your system. Faced the same issue. Try checking your installation and make sure everything is installed properly. Use this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Just uninstall android as well as flutter. Try installing them again. First download and install Flutter. Then download and install Android Studio. Follow the proper installation process. I guess your issue is because of the unproper installation.

After `flutter` installation, open the folder where you have installed it, and open the file *flutter_console* which is a *batch* . It will open a console and then type:

```
flutter doctor
```

This will show you whether all the installation is properly carried out or not. But a better way is to perform proper installation.

Also you need to set *environment variable* after the installation.

---

Here is what happened with me when I installed flutter and android. This is just to show you the issue I had faced after installation

[image]

I then followed what was been said as error and got my flutter and android studio working.

[image]

Comment: Proper installation is indeed important. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal.
Create the folder for your project by typing the command:

```
mkdir my_awesome_project
```

Navigate to the created folder:

```
cd my_awesome_project
```

In the folder type the command for project creation:

```
flutter create myawesomeproject
```

Open the AndroidStudio and then open the created folder.

Now you are ready to run and develop your app.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and simplest way to create new flutter project is to add flutter plugin to android studio/vs code and selecting SDK dir and then you can simply create new flutter project by clicking on buttons
and you can check flutter official [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor)